# Start Mongodb server in two modes parallely

Tags: mongodb

I have installed **mongo db** in my local system, i am aware that at any point in time we can start the mongo using mongod service.

- in **normal mode** which will run on port 27017
- in **rest API mode** where we can query to collections and db's which normally runs on mongo port + 1000

i want to start both mode together, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add modify your mongod config file to enable http.

add following config line, see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

```
net:
   http:
     enabled: true
```

or add parameter in the command line

`mongod --httpinterface`

Comment: This solved my problem, by enabling http interface it allows me to connection to api and shell interface together.

Answer (score 1):

You can start multiple instances of mongod. You just have to make sure that they're using different ports and different dbpaths.

To run two separate instances of mongod

```
mongod
```

This will start a mongod instance on port 27017 and use dbpath /data/db

Start another command prompt and type in

```
mongod --port 27018 --dbpath /data/db2
```

Just make sure that you have a folder named db2 inside your data folder in your c drive. That's where it stores the data.

Additionally, if you're on Node.js, the MongoDB Node.js driver provides a server method where you can start a mongod instance programatically.

```
var mongo = require("mongodb"); 

var server = new mongo.Server('localhost', 27017, { auto_reconnect : true} );
```

This will create a server in what you are calling the Rest API mode.

And then you can simply start mongod from command prompt specifying some other port and dbpath.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which we can start two instance of mondo or not!. but try this:

Run one of then through `service mongod start` and second one directly by running binary file (e.g. /usr/bin/mondodb). (also you can run both of them directly from CLI.)

In second mode, you most give appropriate parameter for mondo (e.g. path for config file). If you don't know how to give/pass parameters to mondo's binary file, see `man mongodb` or go and read `/etc/init.d/mongod` (in Debian based distributions), it give you useful information)

Unfortunately I don't have an installed mongoDB on my machine, so I can't give you exact commands.

Comment: the way you suggested is use to start monogo server, but man mongo did not help + i can start the server at a time one only. i mean on one port only, and what i wanted is it should start rest api too.

Comment: 'man mongo' give useful information to you, to learn how to run mongo and give it a path to the config file, or run it on a specific port. I suggest run mondo normally via command line, and also modify mongo config file (to started in rest api mode) and then start second instance of mongo throuth CLI, but give it new config file to started via new config file (rest api mode)

Comment: there is --rest parameter when starting the server however if i start with rest the other instance stops.

Comment: did you start both instance from CLI with correct parameters? (do not use command like '/etc/init.d/mongod start' OR 'service mondod start')

Comment: i start service using service mondod start command, but with rest parameter it stops other instance.

Comment: No, don't do that, service restart or service start commands, check pid filed and so kill running instance, Start both instance from command line (e.g. /usr/bin/mondo -c config.cfg)  BUT with customized parameters

Comment: I repeat my first note, I'm not sure we can start two instance of mongo at the same time (parallel). Search and check whether can we do that or not!!. IF yes, then come and try to find how to do that